# Creating a DMG file . MonoDevelop (OSX) Version 3.0.6

Tags: macos, installation, monodevelop, dmg, software-packaging

I'm using MonoDevelop version 3.0.6 to develop a C#.NET project on OSX.

I'm about to pull my hair out. The UI is so frigging NON-intuitive!

I would like to package my project up in an installer (.dmg file). I've read that it's possible but the MonoDevelop UI is so F'ing messy that it's hard to find anything.

Can somebody tell me:

1) Is it possible?
2) How is it done?

Thanks for saving my brain from exploding!

Answer (score 0):

I am running MonoDevelop on Windows and would like to build a dmg file so that Mac OS X users can run it too. There seems to be no way to do this.